# What is the distinction between 联 and 连

Tags: vocabulary

There are two characters 联 and 连. They are both pronounced lián, and they both mean "to join" in the dictionary. What is the distinction between them?

Comment: As a side note, it is believed by one of the Qing-dynasty annotators of the Shuowen Jiezi, Duan Yucai 段玉裁, that both were variant characters from different dynasties for the same word (周人用聯字，漢人用連字，古今字也). I've not seen modern analyses on this though. This 聯~連 word has also been linked to Tibetan གྲལ _gral_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

连 is usually to connect in a physical way, i.e. 连线 (draw a line between two entities), 连接 (to connect things). 联 is more metaphysical, i.e. 联合 (to union), 联系 (connection, in the metaphoric sense), 联络 (to communicate).

Answer (score 1):

> ... they both mean "to join"

The fact is, they are two different words that contain the meaning of "to join/ connect" when they are used as a verb

- Both **联**在一起 and **连**在一起 mean "to **join** together"

Their other meanings do not overlap with each other.

连 also means "consecutive"

- 连续(consecutive/ continuous) cannot be changed to 联续
- 连年征战 (year after year of fighting) cannot be changed to 联年征战

~

联 also means " to ally"

- 联盟(alliance/ coalition) cannot be changed to 連盟
- 联宋灭金 (ally with the Song Dynasty to destroy the Jin Dynasty) cannot be changed to 連宋灭金

Answer (score 1):

联 doesn't really mean "to join" though. It's generally used to denote "ally" or "unite." For example, 聯合國, 聯軍, 聯盟.

The two characters have overlaps and can be used interchangably at times.

Answer (score 1):

Although `连` and `联` both mean `连接`(connect) and `联合`(join), there are some subtle differences in their usage.

In general:

- `连` focuses more on physical connection, which can refer to the continuous connection of things in space or time.
- `联` is more inclined to abstract union, emphasizing the joint cooperation of organizations, groups, concepts, etc. in thoughts, goals or actions.

#### about `连`

- verb.

`连接`（**connect** , **join**）

> 把电脑和路由器用网线**连**起来。
>
> **Connect** the computer and router with a network cable.

> 这个开口环是用来**连接**链条两头的。
>
> The opened link is used to **join** the two ends of the chain.

- adverb.

`连续, 相接`  (**in succession**, **be joined**)

> 他**连**(续)打了好几枪，居然一次都没中靶。
>
> He shot several times **in a row**, but none of them hit the target.

> 这些树木**连**成一片。
>
> The trees are **joined** together.

- verb.

`联合`(**union**)

> 这场比赛需要我们**连**同其他队伍一起合作完成。
>
> This game requires us to work **together with** other teams to complete this game.

- preposition.

`包括` (include)

> 这个面包**连**包装袋一共有1千克。
>
> This bread **including** the packaging bag weighs 1 kilogram in total.

- preposition.

It expresses emphasis (usually used with the character `也` or `都`), and contains the meaning of `甚至(even)`.

> 他**连**句道歉的话**也**没有说。
>
> He didn't **even** say sorry.

- noun.

It represents a modern military organizational unit. [`连`](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BF%9E) **Company (military unit)**。

> 他在战斗中表现突出，受到**连长**的表扬。
>
> He was commended by the **company commander** for his distinguished performance in the battle.

#### about `联`

It means `联合` or `联结`.

- verb.

`联合`( join, unite )

> 我们需要**联合**起来反对恐怖主义。
>
> We need to **unite** against terrorism.

> 我们决定**联合**其他公司共同开发新的市场战略。
>
> We decided to **join forces with** other companies to develop a new market strategy.

`联系`( connect, contact )

> 手机帮助人们与他人建立**联系**。
>
> Mobile phones help people **connect** with others.

> 你可以通过电子邮件跟我们**联系**。
>
> You can **contact** us by e-mail.

- noun.

`联盟`( alliance, league, union )

> 该**联盟**已准备好采取必要行动。
>
> The **alliance** stands ready to do what is necessary.

> 他参加了一些职业棒球次级**联盟**的比赛。
>
> He played some minor **league** baseball.

> 这就是默克尔总理表示不会建立“债务**联盟**”的原因。
>
> That is why Chancellor Merkel has said that there will be no "debt **union**".

`联络/联系` ( contact, connection )

> 我和叔父很少**联络**。
>
> I don't have much **contact** with my uncle.

> 这两个想法之间有何**联系**?
>
> What is the **connection** between the two ideas?

- noun.

It represents well-structured antithetical phrases in poetry.

[`对联(对仗工整的语句)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duilian_(poetry))( poetic couplet )，`上联`，`下联`。

> 他在门上贴了红色的**对联**。
>
> He put up red **couplets** on the doors.

> 这首诗的**上联**和**下联**都写得很好。
>
> Both the **first** and **second** **couplets** of this poem are well written.